# I don't know how to write a Rewrite Rule that involves a parameter in the original url (in my .htaccess)

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I'm trying to rewrite this...

http://site.com/product.php?pProductID=ABC-PRD-CODE

TO

http://site.com/front/product.php?pStyleId=ABC-PRD-CODE

So far I've tried this in my htaccess but it seems to cause and error and just bounce back to the index page.

`RewriteRule ^product\.php\?pProductID=(.*) front/product.php?pStyleId=$1`

Can someone please tell me what I'm doing wrong? Do you need to see the rest of the htaccess to see if something else is interfering with this rule?

Comment: Do you actually mean *redirect* instead of *rewrite*?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The query string is not included in the RewriteRule. You'll have to use a RewriteCond for that. `%1` is replaced with the first capture group of a rewrite condition. See [the documentation](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_rewrite.html) for more information.

```
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^pProductID=(.*)$
RewriteRule ^product\.php$ front/product.php?pStyleId=%1 [L]
```

Comment: Just tried it and it worked perfectly, **THANK YOU** @sumurai8